# How do I grab the header in an area?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, 3d-view, add-on

I want to delete a context of an area except the header but there's no `header` method inside of `bpy.context.window.screen.areas.`

[image]

According to [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) page I think `show_menus` method is the header thing but this one also doesn't belong to the `areas` class. The structure is so bizzare and complex.

Where is the header method?

Answer (score 2):

I find the manual's [*Window System Introduction*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/introduction.html) a helpful means of discovering the names of the various parts of the Blender Window.  These part names carry over mostly intact to the Python `bpy` interface as well.

The main Blender window sub-windows are called *areas*.  Each area is a container for an editor.  The area container is further subdivided into up to 5 *regions*, only two of which are always visible: the *main* region and the *header* region. The other areas include the toolbar on the right, the side panel on the right, and the last operation panel on the lower left.

You can't have a header without the main region and you can't have a main region without a header.

However, the header is a type of menu and you can create menus that mimic it in full or in part.  These menus can pop up in the main region.  Most of the context menus in the 3D Viewport are submenus of the header menu, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Area is the whole editor. The header area is defined in a special header class. There is usually just one for the header area in each editor. And that class is where you place your content of the header then. Menus, buttons, dropdown menus.

So you don't want an area, but simply the name of the header class.

[image]

Comment: Is that `Header` same to `bpy.types.Header`?

Comment: @sniffingdoggo  If somewhere earlier in the code there's a line like `from bpy.types import Header` than yes it is the same.  (In this case there is such a statement.  Areas are subdivided into _Regions_.  The header is one of the regions of an area.